# How to receive Apostle promotions in the very late game?

Tags: civilization-6

In the beginning of the game, after you have bought an Apostle, you typically get to choose between two different promotions for that Apostle the following turn.

However, in the very late game, after you have bought like 20-30 apostles, you do not get the option to promote an Apostle the turn after they spawned any more.

So, in the late game, how can I get promotions for my apostles?

Answer (score 1):

You can't promote in other ways, you only get promotion upon build. There is a whole thread here about this issue [here](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/cannot-promote-apostles.602369/).

Some people say it's a bug (and blame Mont St. Michel for it), some people. say you have limited promotions. Personally I tend to agree with the latter.